# Cannot validate HTML5 Boilerplate meta tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, meta-tags, microsoft-edge

I am having trouble consistently with submitting my HTML for validation, and getting this error returned:

```
Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

What is wrong with this? Honestly, I don't even know what it does. Should I just cut it from the code?

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/x-ua-compatible_and_html5/

Comment: Some guys in HTML WG have thought it's of their responsibility to define exact set of allowed meta elements while actually it's not. So, to make page valid, we are forced to use server response header.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked that your page works OK on recent versions of IE both in “Quirks Mode” and in “Standard Mode”, you can remove the tag. Otherwise, keep this part:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

That’s assuming that your pages have been written for “Standards Mode”, as any new pages should. The `meta` tag helps to put IE into that mode, see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the lines. It is only the tell IE to use latest rendering engine.

Read more on - http://blog.yjl.im/2011/01/bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute.html

Comment: “Only”? The tag has its use and effect, so I would not recommend it just because it has exactly this effect.

Answer (score 0):

As it is only aimed at IE, I believe you can wrap it in conditional IE tags and that should get you past the validator.

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Sadly, IE does not recognize X-UA-Compatible in an IE conditional.

from: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/html5boilerplate/bRtrFSrKjtI/SFTzSqmUH9AJ